# Reading the array name itself (not its content) from JSON using java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON like this -

```
result = [ 
       { "value1": [
           { 
             "number" : "3",
             "title" : "hello_world"
           },

           { 
             "number" : "2",
             "title" : "hello_world"
           }
          ]
       },
       { "value2": [
           { 
             "number" : "4",
             "title" : "hello_world"
           },

           { 
             "number" : "5",
             "title" : "hello_world"
           }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I want to get result[0] i.e "value1" and result[1] i.e "value2".
Below is my code for parsing this Json -

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray resultArray = jsonParser.parse(result.getAsJsonArray("result"));
```

Above code is working fine and I am getting 2 Json arrays. Now for getting value1 I have written this code-

```
String v = resultArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("value1").getAsString();
```

But this is not giving me value1 rather than its throwing error "java.lang.IllegalStateException". What I am doing wrong here?

Please note that I want to read array name of "value1" and "value2" itself as string and not its inside content.Means print line should print value1 as output.

Comment: use gson library it will save your time

Comment: @ysl I am using gson library only. In fact I am able to get the inside content of "value1" and "value2" but how to read that "value1" and "value2" itself.

Comment: value1 is not string, its jsonArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value1` is not `String` but rather a `JsonArray`,

when you call `getAsString()` method, it will throw Exception telling  you the value is not of a String object.

few Options :

1- read the value as JsonArray then convert it to String using toString method:

```
String v = resultArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("value1").toString();
```

2- use toString method directly on JsonElement itself (return value of get("value1")

```
String v = resultArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("value1").toString();
```

I normally use option one because it enforces the check.

**EDIT:**

After reading comment, basically what is required is to get all the keys of each JsonObject within each Object

you need to loop through the array and get all they entrySet().(not tested but should work)

```
for(JsonElement element : resultArray){
   JsonObject next= element.getAsJsonObject();
   for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : next.entrySet()){
     System.out.println(entry.getKey()); // <-- prints out value1 and value2
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine but this is not what I want. It is giving inside contents of value1 i.e [{"number" : "3","title" : "hello_world"}, {"number" : "2","title" : "hello_world"}]. I dont want this, I want to read explicitly "value1" as string.

Comment: @user7348570 not sure what you mean, the string representation of value1 is as u described, what do you exactly want?

Comment: @user7348570 can you edit your question and show the `desired output` please?

Comment: I want the names because in my case value1 and value2 array keeps changing i.e sometime value1 comes 1st and sometime value2 comes 1st. So , I want to check it by if condition say if resultArray[0] == "value1" then do something otherwise do something else. So for this I want to read the names of array itself.

Comment: @user7348570 updated the answer mate, what you looking for is the entrySet() method on JsonObject;

Comment: Yup its working. Thank you very much buddy. One small change, please update your code from "object.entrySet()" to next.entrySet().